# How to route CodeIgniter with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to use Angular.js and CodeIgniter together.

With `ngRoute` in my app, I'm setting in my `main.js`:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/test', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/test.html'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
});
```

In my `routes.php`, I'm setting:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['(:any)'] = "home";
```

And in my `home/index.php`, I have the `<ng-view></ng-view>`.

The thing is, **without** the `html5Mode(true)` (with /#/ on the URL) everything works fine. But otherwise, the partials file works, but the page reloads anyway.

In Inspector Elements, things look like this:

[image: partials/test.html loaded, but the page realoded, and the error "ngView: undefined" showed up]

partials/test.html loaded, but the page realoded, and the error "ngView: undefined" showed up.

I'm still learning Angularjs. Anyone can help?

Comment: i think you need to try this `$route['(.*)'] = "home/index";`

Comment: The page realoads anyway. It is ajax, so it should stay in home/index and doesn't reload when the URL changes.

Comment: Did you set base tag in your html header ? `<base href="/">`

Comment: I setted `<base href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">`

Comment: can you make it more clear this question it's not full understandable

Comment: are you sure that path 'partials/test.html' is understandable to Codeigniter?
try to inspect in chrome console which url Angular try to access and what result. It may have something with your .htaccess and rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

this is a production form (i´m using htaccess)

in the js folder create a app.js
js/app.js

```
//create app module
var app = angular.module("app", []);

//login configuration
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller : "loginController",
        templateUrl : "templates/login.html"
    })
    .when("/home", {
        controller : "homeController",
        templateUrl : "templates/home.html"
    })
});
```

js/controllers/controllers.js

```
//save & delete sessions
app.factory("sesionesControl", function(){
    return {
        //obtenemos una sesión //getter
        get : function(key) {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key)
        },
        //creamos una sesión //setter
        set : function(key, val) {
            return sessionStorage.setItem(key, val)
        },
        //limpiamos una sesión
        unset : function(key) {
            return sessionStorage.removeItem(key)
        }
    }
})

//simple message in bad login
app.factory("mensajesFlash", function($rootScope){
    return {
        show : function(message){
            $rootScope.flash = message;
        },
        clear : function(){
            $rootScope.flash = "";
        }
    }
});

//angular login & logout
app.factory("authUsers", function($http, $location, sesionesControl, mensajesFlash){
    var cacheSession = function(email){
        sesionesControl.set("userLogin", true);
        sesionesControl.set("email", email);
    }
    var unCacheSession = function(){
        sesionesControl.unset("userLogin");
        sesionesControl.unset("email");
    }

    return {
        //return authUsers
        login : function(user){
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/login_ci_angularjs/login/loginUser',
                method: "POST",
                data : "email="+user.email+"&password="+user.password,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data){
                if(data.respuesta == "success"){
                    //if true clear flash messages
                    mensajesFlash.clear();
                    //create session with email
                    cacheSession(user.email);
                    //redirect to home
                    $location.path("/home");
                }else if(data.respuesta == "incomplete_form"){
                    mensajesFlash.show("The email & user are required");
                }else if(data.respuesta == "failed"){
                    mensajesFlash.show("The email ore password are wrong");
                }
            }).error(function(){
                $location.path("/")
            })
        },
        //close session
        logout : function(){
            return $http({
                url : "http://localhost/login_ci_angularjs/login/logoutUser"
            }).success(function(){
                //delete session in sessionStorage
                unCacheSession();
                $location.path("/login");
            });
        }
    }
})

app.controller("homeController", function($scope, sesionesControl, authUsers){
    $scope.email = sesionesControl.get("email");
    $scope.logout = function(){
        authUsers.logout();
    }
})

//permisos
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, authUsers){
    //url that the user can access
    var rutasPrivadas = ["/home","/info","/login"];
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
        if(in_array($location.path(),rutasPrivadas) && !authUsers.isLoggedIn()){
            $location.path("/login");
        }
        //if user go to login (if the session exist redirect to home)
        if(($location.path() === '/login') && authUsers.isLoggedIn()){
            $location.path("/home");
        }
    })
})

//controller loginController
app.controller("loginController", function($scope, $location, authUsers){
    $scope.user = { email : "", password : "" }
    authUsers.flash = "";
    //submit form
    $scope.login = function(){
        authUsers.login($scope.user);
    }
})

//if user has permissions in the url
function in_array(needle, haystack, argStrict){
  var key = '',
  strict = !! argStrict;

  if(strict){
    for(key in haystack){
      if(haystack[key] === needle){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }else{
    for(key in haystack){
      if(haystack[key] == needle){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

templates/login.htm

```
<form name="loginUserForm">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>form login</legend>

        <div class="row">
            <div ng-show="flash">
                <div data-alert class="alert-box alert round">{{ flash }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" required placeholder="mail@mail.com" ng-model="user.email">
            </div>
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" required placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="!loginUserForm.$valid" ng-click="login(user)" class="button expand round">Login</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Login.php controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{
    public  function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view("login");
    }

    //called from angular controller.js
    public function loginUser(){
        if($this->input->post("email") && $this->input->post("password"))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
                echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "incomplete_form"));
            }else{
                $this->load->model("login_model");
                $email = $this->input->post("email");
                $password = $this->input->post("password");
                $loginUser = $this->login_model->loginUser($email,$password);
                if($loginUser === true){
                    echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "success"));
                }else{
                    echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "failed"));
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("respuesta" => "incomplete_form"));
        }
    }

    public function logoutUser(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }
}
```

apllications/views/login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CI & Angular</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- with this ng-view, we load all views -->
<div class="row" ng-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/home.html

```
<h3 class="subheader">Hello {{ email }}</h3>
<button ng-click="logout()" class="large-12 button expand">Logout</button>
```